# Is it possible to customize Table of content in PISA to make it clickable to content?

Tags: python, django, pisa

I would like to customize the built-in table of content in [Pisa](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa/) so that it includes clickable links to allow the user to  navigate to the content.

Comment: I’ve linked to Pisa; but I’m not entirely sure it’s the thing you’re talking about.